# How to map color array in Paint in Java?

Tags: java, swing, colors, paint

Below is the code. I am getting error in this line

```
Paint[] p=new Paint[]{cols};
```

but if I use

```
Paint[] p=new Paint[]{cols[1]};
```

it doesn't give an error.

```
    Color[] cols = new Color[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cols[i] = Color.getHSBColor((float) i / n, 1, 1);

    }
    Paint[] p=new Paint[]{cols};
    return cols;
```

Answer (score 2):

`p` is an array of `Paint`. `cols` is another array. `p` cannot contain `cols`, because the objects in `p` must be `Paint`, not arrays.

If you want to put the contents of `cols` into `p`, you can do this:

```
Paint[] p = new Paint[cols.length]; // create a new array with the same length as `cols`
System.arraycopy(cols, 0, p, 0, cols.length); // copy the contents
```

which amounts to iterating through the length of the array and copying across each element.

But I'm not sure why you have the `cols` array at all if you actually want a `Paint` array. You could just do this:

```
Paint[] p = new Paint[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    p[i] = Color.getHSBColor((float) i / n, 1, 1);
}
```